# Reusing StackExchange.Redis ConnectionMultiplexer

Tags: redis, stackexchange.redis

Dears;

You can reuse StackExchange.Redis ConnectionMultiplexer by using the following code. It can be used in any layer of your code.

```
public class RedisSharedConnection
{
    private static Lazy<ConnectionMultiplexer> lazyConnection = new Lazy<ConnectionMultiplexer>(() =>
    {
        ConnectionMultiplexer connectionMultiplexer = ConnectionMultiplexer.Connect(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["RedisConnectionString"].ConnectionString);
        connectionMultiplexer.PreserveAsyncOrder = false;
        return connectionMultiplexer;
    });

    public static ConnectionMultiplexer Connection
    {
        get
        {
            return lazyConnection.Value;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because its not a question